# socialite Google Login shows "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I am trying to setup Google Login using socialite in Laravel. But when I enter the Google credentials, it shows:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

for  the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/redirect/google`.

**My web.php is:**

```
Route::get('/redirect/google', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback/google', 'SocialAuthController@callback');
```

**services.php:**

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => '-----.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret' => '---------',
    'redirect' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/google'
],
```

**SocialAuthController.php:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\SocialAccountService;
use Socialite;

class SocialAuthController extends Controller {
    //
    public function redirect(){
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function callback(SocialAccountService $service) {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('google')->user());
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**SocialAccount.php :**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SocialAccount extends Model {
    //
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'provider_user_id', 'provider'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Migration for social_accounts_table**

```
class CreateSocialAccountsTable extends Migration { 
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('social_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->string('provider_user_id');
            $table->string('provider');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('social_accounts');
    }
}
```

**SocialAccountService.php**

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User as ProviderUser;

class SocialAccountService {
    public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser) {
        $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider('google')
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {
            $account = new SocialAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'google'
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

            if (!$user) {
                $user = User::create([
                    'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                    'role' => 'user',
                    'password' => '',
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();
            return $user;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Socialite will not work In local

Answer (score 0):

In your services, you have

```
'redirect' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/google'
```

After authentication, Google cannot access your domain `http://127.0.0.1`(localhost). You will have to try it with a production URL

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, the  issue is my redirect()->back() call in callback function. I still need to find how to redirect back to original source page, but redirecting to home, has solved this issue.